# Google Cloud Bigtable Python Client Performance Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable, google-cloud-python

I'm running into a performance issue with Google Cloud Bigtable Python Client. I'm working on a flask API that writes to and reads from a GCP Bigtable instance. The API uses the python client to communicate with Bigtable, and was deployed to GCP App Engine flexible environment.

Under low traffic, the API works fine. However during a load test, the endpoints that reads and writes to Bigtable suffers a huge performance decrease compare to a similar endpoint that doesn't communicate with Bigtable. Also, a large percentage of requests went to the endpoint receives a `502 Bad Gateway`, even when health check was turned off in App Engine.

I'm aware of that the client is currently in Alpha. I wonder if the performance issue is known, or if anyone also ran into the same issue

**Update**

I found a documentation from Google stating:

> There are issues with the network connection. Network issues can
>   reduce throughput and cause reads and writes to take longer than
>   usual. In particular, you'll see issues if your clients are not
>   running in the same zone as your Cloud Bigtable cluster.

In my case, my client is in a different region, by moving it to the same region had a huge increase in performance. However the performance issue still exist, and the recommendation from the documentation is to put client in the same zone as Bigtable.

I also considered using Container engine or Compute Engine where it is easier to specify the zone, but I want stay with App Engine for its autoscale functionality and managed services.

Answer (score 3):

Bigtable client take somewhere between 3 ms to 20 ms to complete each request, and because python is single threaded, during that period of time it will just wait until the response comes back. The best solution we found was for any writes, publish the request to Pubsub, then use Dataflow to write to Bigtable. It is significantly faster because publishing a message in Python would take way below 1 ms to complete, and because Dataflow can be set to exactly the same region as Bigtable, and it is easy to parallel, it can write much faster.

Though it doesn't solve the scenario where you need frequent read or write need to be instantaneous